# Output not appearing on python 2.7

Tags: python

So, i was working on a program with python 2.7 and the output was not showing up. Heres the source code:

```
print("What operator do you want to use?")
operator = input()
print("Enter the first value")
val1 = int(input())
print("Enter the second value")
val2 = int(input())
if val1 == 45 and val2 == 3 and operator == "*":
    print(555)
if val1 == 56 and val2 == 9 and operator == "+":
    print(77)
if val1 == 56 and val2 == 6 and operator == "/":
    print(4)
elif operator == "/":
    i = val1/val2
    print(i)
elif operator == "*":
    j = val1*val2
    print(j)
elif operator == "+":
    k = val1+val2
    print(k)
elif operator == "-":
    l = val1-val2
    print(l)
```

Heres my inputs:

```
What operator do you want to use?
"+"
Enter the first value
20
Enter the second value
20

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Where the result was supposed to appear, theres just a blank and if i enter the operator without quotes this error happens:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/newPythonProject/Tests.py", line 2, in <module> operator = input() File "<string>", line 1 + ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: Type `+`, not `"+"` with the quotes. And put the message into the input method as `input("What operator do you want to use?")` you get just one line and get rid of the print

Answer (score 2):

You included quotation marks in your input for the operator.

Comment: Ya but this is what i get when i dont put quoatation:
"" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/newPythonProject/Tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    operator = input()
  File "<string>", line 1
    +
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing""

Answer (score -1):

It seems you entered the operator in quotes

Comment: Ya but this is what i get when i dont put quoatation: "" Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/newPythonProject/Tests.py", line 2, in <module> operator = input() File "<string>", line 1 + ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing""

Answer (score -1):

In python 3.x  the `input()` function does not interpret, it always returns a string.

However, in python 2.x the `input()` function returns the most likely data-type, sloppily said. As you want your input to be a string you can use `raw_input`, which does not interpret the input and always returns a string.

This said, your input is already a string. Thus, your quotation marks "" are not just redundant, they alter the input string.

As python 2.7, in your case, interprets its input, the casting `int(input())` is not inherently necessary, as `input()` will automatically assume that your input `20` is of type `int`.

Use the below code and your function should work.

```
print("What operator do you want to use?")
operator = raw_input()
print("Enter the first value")
val1 = int(input())
print("Enter the second value")
val2 = int(input())
if val1 == 45 and val2 == 3 and operator == "*":
    print(555)
if val1 == 56 and val2 == 9 and operator == "+":
    print(77)
if val1 == 56 and val2 == 6 and operator == "/":
    print(4)
elif operator == "/":
    i = val1/val2
    print(i)
elif operator == "*":
    j = val1*val2
    print(j)
elif operator == "+":
    k = val1+val2
    print(k)
elif operator == "-":
    l = val1-val2
    print(l)
```

With following inputs:

```
What operator do you want to use?
+
Enter the first value
20
Enter the second value
20
```

Comment: Ya but this is what i get when i dont put quoatation: "" Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:/Users/USER/PycharmProjects/newPythonProject/Tests.py", line 2, in <module> operator = input() File "<string>", line 1 + ^ SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing""

Comment: You are right. You can solve your problem by using `raw_input` instead of `input.` I will adapt my answer on this one.